# Name of this repeated definitions replaced by overloaded functions code smell/refactoring pattern

Tags: java, refactoring

I had a set of functions which were doing repetitive things + something more.

(This is a simplified code snippet)

```java
static class Configuration {
    String site;
    List<Category> categories;
}
static class Category {
    String type;
    BoundaryData[] boundaryData;
}
static class BoundaryData {
    Double value;
    ....
}

public Configuration getConfiguration(String siteName) {
    if (siteName == null) return null;
    
    Optional<Configuration> configuration = listOfCategories.stream()
                                    .filter((c) -> c.getSite().equals(siteName))
                                    .findFirst();

    if (configuration.isEmpty()) return null;

    return configuration.get();
}

public Category getCategories(String siteName, String categoryType) {
    // Repeat the same configuration fetch code above
    // Searching for categories
}

public BoundaryData getBoundaryData(String siteName, String categoryType, Double value) {
    // Repeat the same configuration and category fetch code above
    // Searching for BoundaryData
}
```

One of my code reviewers suggested that why don't I name the function something specific and chain the use them in each more granular functions call. Something like this -

```java
public Configuration findConfig(String siteName) {
    if (siteName == null) return null;
    
    Optional<Configuration> configuration = listOfCategories.stream()
                                    .filter((c) -> c.getSite().equals(siteName))
                                    .findFirst();

    if (configuration.isEmpty()) return null;

    return configuration.get();
}

public Category findConfig(String siteName, String categoryType) {
    Configuration config = findConfig(siteName);
    if (config == null) return null;
    
    Optional<Category> category = config.getCategories().stream()
                                    .filter((c) -> c.getType().equals(categoryType))
                                    .findFirst();

    if (category.isEmpty()) return null;

    return category.get();
}

public BoundaryData findConfig(String siteName, String categoryType, Double value) {
    Category category = findConfig(siteName, categoryType);
    if (category == null) return null;

    Optional<BoundaryData> boundaryData = Arrays.stream(category.getBoundaryData())
                                    .filter((c) -> c.getValue() > value)
                                    .findFirst();

    if (boundaryData.isEmpty()) return null;

    return boundaryData.get();
}
```

I wonder if there is some name to such a refactoring. For e.g. This seems like code smell `Duplicated Code`. But this is something more specific.

EDIT: This seems similar - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/301484/how-is-this-pattern-called

EDIT: Apparently they are called `convenience overloads`

Comment: Are you saying the _refactored code_ seems like a code smell? Because what you had originally is duplicated code. The refactored code reuses existing code. Though I would _not_ have changed all method names to `findConfig`, as only one of them actually returns a `Configuration`. And if feasible, I'd consider making the return types of all the methods `Optional`.

Comment: No, I was wondering if there is a name to such a refactoring. Or when do we use such a refactoring.

I have seen this in a lot of places where one method calls another one with some default value for an overloaded method. Something like super() in constructors but with a small difference.

Comment: May be you are looking for the so called **DRY: Don't Repeat Yourself - Software Design Principle** here's an article on medium you might want to glance over [dry-do-not-repeat-yourself](https://medium.com/@learnstuff.io/dry-do-not-repeat-yourself-8518055b4cf). Violations of **DRY** are referred to as **WET: We Enjoy Typing, Write Everything Twice, Waste Everyone's Time.**

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but your can replace `if (category.isEmpty()) return null;` with `category.orElse(null)`. That said, the point of using `Optional` is null safety, so the method should return an Optional and use the Optional methods such as `orElse` to deal with the value, instead of checking for null.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the code you give us is fictitious to represent the actual use case. With that assumption in mind and some interpolation, here is a suggestion to make the code read slightly better. Please, accept my apologies if my interpolation is off.

```java
public Optional<Configuration> findConfig(Optional<String> siteName) {
    return siteName
            .flatMap(
                    (s) -> lisOfConfigurations.stream()
                            .filter((c) -> c.hasSite(s))
                            .findFirst());
}

public Optional<Category> findCategory(Optional<String> siteName, String categoryType) {
    return findConfig(siteName)
            .map((config) -> config.getCategory(categoryType));
}


public Optional<BoundaryData> findBoundaryData(Optional<String> siteName, String categoryType, Double value) {
    return findCategory(siteName, categoryType)
            .flatMap((category) -> category.getSuitableBoundary(value));
}
```

Ideally, however, the caller should do the null check on the site or map on an optional. This would save us some of the optional mappings or if you prefer, the null checks. You may assert (or throw an exception if the site is null).

At any point, if you want to move from Optional to nullable value, I believe you can use `optionalValue.orElse(null)`, in case you do not control the interface.

```java
class Configuration {
   String site;
   List<Category> categories;
   
   public String getSite() {
       return site;
   }

   public boolean hasSite(String siteName) {
       return site.equals(siteName);
   }
   

   public Category getCategory(String CategoryType) {
       return categories.stream()
               .filter((c) -> c.getType().equals(CategoryType))
               .findAny()
               .orElse(null);
   }
}

class Category {
   String type;
   BoundaryData[] boundaryData;


   public Optional<BoundaryData> getSuitableBoundary(Double value) {
       return Arrays.stream(boundaryData)
               .filter((c) -> c.getValue() > value)
               .findFirst();
   }

   public String getType() {
       return type;
   }
}

class BoundaryData {
   Double value;

   public Double getValue() {
       return value;
   }
}
```